# Mongo Aggregate $group map and $project array still including null values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have a collection of data like so below (mongo ids changed to more readable names)

```
[{
    "name":"John",
    "_type":"checkin",
    "event":"A"
},
{
    "name":"John",
    "_type":"checkin",
    "event":"B"
},
{
    "name":"Sally",
    "_type":"checkin",
    "event":"B"
},
{
    "name":"Michael",
    "_type":"checkin",
    "event":"A"
},
{
    "name":"Michael",
    "_type":"checkin",
    "event":"C"
}]
```

Using Mongo Aggregate query is it possible/how can i get to a result like so?

```
[{
    "name":"John",
    "events":["A", "B", null]
},
{
    "name":"Sally",
    "events":[null, "B", null]
},
{
    "name":"Michael",
    "events":["A", null, "C"]
}]
```

I've tried everything i know how to try and map the data, currently i'm back to this

```
[{
    "$match":{
        "_type":"checkin"
    }
},
{ 
    "$group": {
        "_id":"$name",
        "event":{
            "$push":"$event"
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: just inverse parameters in your **`$group`**: `{ "$group": {"_id":"$name", "events":{"$push":"$event"}}`

Comment: UThat doesn't keep the null values in the correct spot though, I need them to line up as in the example so that each event has the same index. If there was some way of keeping a master record of each distinct event and then querying all checkin items and mapping them then it would be great..

Comment: then you may achieve this by grouping on `_type`, and use [**`$cond`**]()https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/ to push the value as you want. But this will work only if you know all possible `name` in advance. You should add an index in event instead so `event` would looks like `event: {type: "A", index: 1}`

Comment: Thanks Felix I appreciate the link. I was looking through the documentation and still have a bit of a headspin. Is there any chance that you could help a brother out with an answer including some example code of how to achieve the result? 

Do I need to do a $project with a nested $push and a $cond inside the $push?